# Two Kubernetes pods accessing the same database

Tags: spring, kubernetes

My SpringBoot application is scheduled to run at 1 UTC each day for some data collection and put that in the database. We are using Kubernetes and we have two pods accessing the same database. The database is at some other location for which we have a connection string which is the same in both pods.

The problem is both of my pods wake up at 1 UTC and add duplicate entries in the database? How can I ensure that only one pod is talking to the database?  Is this application is not ideal for k8s deployment?

Comment: What are the pods doing? Why are there two pods writing into it? I would like to understand what's the idea behind. What is the goal...

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but for anybody else, look into [ShedLock](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock).  It handles locking across distributed nodes and is pretty easy to implement.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31376103)